# Reachability notification not getting called. Using tonymillion/Reachability

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, reachability

I'm using this library to get notified when the connection status on the device changes. I don't understand WHY this is not working! I'm doing exactly what I'm reading in the documentation in github!

When the app starts, the notification gets posted but when I open the settings, turn on/off airplane mode and go back to the app (without closing it) the notifiation does not get called.

I have also subscribed to get the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification notifications... both methods DO EXISTS in the app... am I missing something?!?

This is in my viewDidLoad:

```
self.reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:kServerURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChangedInApp:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
[self.reach startNotifier];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(initializeDateRelatedStuff:)
                                            name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

This is in my dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Is kServerURL an NSString? Also, what's the code for reachabilityChangedInApp:?

Comment: yes it's an NSString with google URL. It's just a function that calls some network dependent methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your application is most likely not a background application and thus suspended once you press the home button to activate airplane mode. Since your app is not running when the reachability changes, it won't get any notification. You will get the notification, however, when network reachability changes while your app is in foreground.

So you probably want to check the reachability when your app enters the foreground in addition to what you have already implemented.

Comment: but wait... with "Not a background application" what do you mean? When I open my app it starts in the same place it was left. It's not a UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend > true. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Yes, when you open your app it starts right where you left. But that doesn't mean that your application continued running after you pressed the home button. You might want to check the [App States and Multitasking Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). If you haven't requested extra time for background execution (like audio or navigation apps could do, for example), your app is suspended when not in foreground. And in this state you can't handle any notifications.